# JSP using JSTL and scriptlets

Tags: jsp, jstl, scriptlet

I have this jsp page with some conditions :

```
<%      
        if (filterPresent.equals("true") && !selectedFilterCategory.isEmpty()){
%>
        <c:if test="${entry.category eq param.selectedFilterCategory}">
<%
        }
%>
                RENDER A TABLE WITH ITEMS

<%
        if ( filterPresent.equals("true") && !selectedFilterCategory.isEmpty() ) {
%>
        </c:if>
<%
       }
%>
```

If that filterPresent value is true I want only some items to be displayed(those that match the category). If it is not present I want to display all the items.

The error I'm getting is :

```
An error occurred at line: 48 in the jsp file: /jsp//ejbChildRule.jsp
Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete BlockStatements
45: %>
46:             <c:if test="${entry.category eq param.selectedFilterCategory}">
47: <%
48:             }
49: %>
50:                 <tr class="<%=currentBackground%>">
51:                             <td  class="<%=currentBackground%>" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap>
```

Can I achieve what I want in this manner ?

Comment: please provide some more lines of code then it will be clearly addressed.

Comment: Mixing taglibs and scriptlets is big trouble. Use the one or the other, not both. I recommend to get rid of scriptlets altogheter as that's considered discouraged since almost a decade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should NOT use any scriptlets, except under very urgent circumstances.

Instead of `<%=currentBackground%>` you may use :

- request.setAttribute("currentBackground", yourObject) inside your Java beans
- or [useBean](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/syntaxref.fm14.html) with getter/setter

then properly use [Expression Language](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html) with ${currentBackground} to fetch yourObject.

Answer (score 1):

That looks rather ugly. Use `<c:if>` for all the clauses. Using scriptlets leads to these kinds of mistakes - unclosed brackets, forgotten semicolons, etc.